# how to omit for loop when there is constrains

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have the following two arrays:

```
A = [1 2;3 4] and B = [1 5 4]
```

I want to do the following operation:

```
for each element of A(call it A(i))
    for each element of B~=b do
        ( (A(i) - 1)/(b-1) ) * ( (A(i) - 5)/(b-5) ) * ( (A(i)- 4)/(b-4) )
    end
end
```

It means that, sometimes the numerator equals to zero, so the product should be zeros. And I want to do the operation for the elements of `B` which are not equal to the `b` in denominator to not make it `Inf`.

How can I do this for the whole matrix `A` instead of using for loop?

Comment: You're not using `B(j)` in the inner loop...?

Comment: Final output would have a size of?

Comment: I don't understand `for each element of B~=b do`

Comment: @Divakar final output will be the same size as A since for each element of A i do the operation on all of the elements of B (for each element of A i have the product created by B elements)

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis yes. for each element of A, i use all the elements of B to create the product

Comment: @Daniel if the element of B to be used be equal to the b the product will be Inf and i don't want this

Comment: What exactly is `b`, is that a scalar or vector or part of `B`?

Comment: @Divakar it is a scalar but it could be equal to one of the elements of B

Comment: @user3482383 In that case there would be six multiplications inside the innermost loop, right? Do you have a working `for` code?

Comment: @ِDivakar consider that each time b is one of the elements of B but i want to have the multiplication for other elements of B to not have Inf. the output will be the same size as A and the number of multiplications for each elements will be 2 two in this example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just do the operation, and correct later:

```
C = (A-1)./(B-1) .* (A-5)./(B-5) .* (A-4)./(B-4)
C(isinf(C)) = 0;
```

or

```
C(B==b) = 0;
```

Possibly you'd need `bsxfun`, I'm not clear on the size of the output you want...

Answer (score 2):

**Code**

```
A = [1 2;3 4];
B = [1 5 4];

m1 = bsxfun(@minus,A,permute([1 5 4],[3 1 2]));
m2 = bsxfun(@minus,B,permute([1 5 4],[3 1 2]));

for k1=1:size(A,1)
    for k2=1:size(A,2)
        t2 = squeeze(bsxfun(@rdivide,m1(k1,k2,:),m2));
        t2(1:size(t2,1)+1:end)=1;
        A1(k1,k2) = prod(t2(:)); %%// Output
    end
end
```

**Output**

```
A1 =

         0   -0.2500
   -0.1111         0
```

You can remove the nested loops, but at least two issues there -

1. You would be going to 4th and 5th dimension with it, using `bsxfun`. So, debugging would be tough.
2. `bsxfun` with higher dimensions to my knowledge seems to get slower.

Comment: I guess this makes the most sense... :)

Comment: here i just gave an example of B, how about if it be a m by n matrix? how should i change the parameters?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Well it was twisted there already. Hope it makes sense now :)

Comment: I think working with bsxfun would be a little difficult especially as you said when i want to remove the for loops. any other way?!

Comment: @user3482383 As I said, if you want to get rid of `for` loops, bsxfun is the only approach I can think of as others like `repmat`, etc. are just variants of loopings. Are you looking to remove `for` loops, just for the sake of it or are you really bothered about the runtime? If later is the case, the edited code here would work and work pretty optimally.

Comment: @user3482383 Also could you confirm the output values look good? We need to make sure that we have a functional code first and then think about removing loops and optimizations stuffs. Go step by step.